# Asp.Net MVC Model Binding to a property type System.Uri got issues with Mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nginx, mono

While debugging on Visual Studio, it comes in pretty fine. Even though there is no default constructor, only the parameterized.

But while hosted over a `nginx` instance in a `linux server`. It throws `System.UriFormatException: Absolute URI is too short`

Although i have implemented a work around of binding it to a string type and then converting it to Uri. But its not a cleaner way.

Has anyone got any ideas about this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i finally got the issue. Internally when doing `GetPropertyValue` in DefaultModelBinder, it compares the Object with string.empty using `Object.Equals(obj, string.Empty)`.

This throws an exception while obj is type System.Uri, as Object.Equals calls Uri.Equals, which then try to type cast emtoy string into type Uri.

See the snippet from https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web.Mvc3/Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs

```
if (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull && Object.Equals(value, String.Empty)) 
{
     return null;
}
```

Solution:
Create a custom binder for type Uri, and inside BindModel set

```
bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false;
```